# iOS - Loading a xib

Tags: ios, uiview, xib

Anyone have any idea why when I use this block of code, it doesn't scale the view to the size of the screen. It looks like it loads the xib file as is and doesn't fit it to the width of the device.

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ReceiptView" owner:self options:NULL];
        self = (ReciptView *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }
    return self;
}
```

And this is the implementation in the controller:

```
-(void) bookNowAction
{
    ReciptView *v = [[ReciptView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:v];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reassigning self in the if block, after you called super initWithFrame. You are essentially wiping out the effect of that call.